# java.lang.AbstractMethodError while implementing mongo db insertOne method in java

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, selenium-webdriver, mongodb-query

I have tried the below.

```
MongoDB mongoDB = new MongoDB(<connection_string>));
MongoDatabase db = mongoDB.getConnection(\<database_name\>);
MongoCollection\<Document\> collection = db.getCollection(\<collection_name\>);

Document documentToInsert = new Document();
documentToInsert.append("lead_id", "64b671e01850084fb0eaa1b0");
documentToInsert.append("tenant_id", "6423d08b6ba5d39df3db3779");
documentToInsert.append("apartment_id", "6423de7fb39ac5ff8851d0a8");
documentToInsert.append("query", "Yes, I have done my tour");
documentToInsert.append("tour_completed_status", "tourCompleted");
documentToInsert.append("sentiment", "neutral");
documentToInsert.append("source", "mark4");
documentToInsert.append("tour_type", "onplatform_inperson");

collection.insertOne(documentToInsert);
```

While debugging the above, at the point when I come to last line, it's throwing the below error.

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void insertOne(java.lang.Object)' of interface com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.

Dependencies for Mongo DB I use are as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.9.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to insert document in Mongo. Can anyone try this and let me know how to resolve this?